# Drupal 7 auction module or something

Tags: 7, ubercart

I'm search for a few days now. But I cannot find a good auction module for Drupal 7. **I have try the module: [uc_auction](https://drupal.org/project/uc_auction) but the highest bid did not save in my shopping card only my sell price.** I have no idea of there is an other option for een auction system but I cannot find him.

Who have a suggestion for me? I'm using the module Ubercart for my website now.

Comment: If you are using Ubercart, posing a bugreport in uc_auction module's issue queue is most straightforward approach.

Comment: It is a bug that has not been fixed. See this thread https://drupal.org/node/348592.

Comment: Well, have you tried anything else? Have you tried to look on your own first? There is a module named simply [Auction](https://drupal.org/project/auction) on Drupal.org so when you don't even mention it, it looks like you haven't try to find alternatives. Sure, probably that's only impression, so please tell us a bit more :)

Answer (score 1):

[Auction](https://drupal.org/project/auction) module provides auction functionality. Commerce integration is an option.

> Structure: Auctions are entities with start / end date, starting
>   price, minimum price and instant buy price. Auction content type with
>   auction reference field is created upon installation.

or

[Commerce Auction](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_auction) module lets you create auction/reverse auction websites using drupal commerce. see the [Demo](http://www.drupalauction.com/)

Features

- Allows creating auctions and reverse auctions using drupal commerce
- Automatic auction timeout extension
- Automatically adds auctioned product to the winner's shopping cart
- By default disables remove and edit quantity fields of auctioned products in shopping cart
- Global and per-auction bid limits (like uc_auction)
- Lists bids using views

> [image]

Comment: I saw this indeed. But I'm using the Ubercart module. The Ubercart module is installed and everything is works. I'm using the Auction module now. But my Drupal cannot send a email to the user with the highest bid. I get the error: Unable to send e-mail. Contact the site administrator if the problem persists.

Comment: "Unable to send e-mail. Contact the site administrator if the problem persists", it is because of you not configured the email settings properly and not because of the module and here is the link to solve this one https://www.google.ae/search?q=drupal+nable+to+send+e-mail.+Contact+the+site+administrator+if+the+problem+persists&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&gws_rd=cr&ei=n2Z7Up-JK4qntAat6oDACA

Comment: I'm using the phpmailer module now. Test mails are sending but not when I place a bid.